# Limit images show in post to last six

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have with me a set of posts created from a scaffold and images uploaded using paperclip gem. I would like to show on each users profile the last six images from the users last posts and for that I am filtering as such

```
<% @posts.limit(6).each do |tweet| %>
  <% if post.media.present? %> 
    <%= link_to image_tag(post.media.url(:thumb)), tweet %><br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I have the posts arranged as such

```
@posts = user.posts.order('created_at desc')
```

My question is. Why is it that when using the above code, NO image is displayed. On upping the count to 9, I get three images displayed, to 12 i get six images displayed and so on

Comment: Close parentheses for image_tag

Comment: Are you using Rails 5? If yes, you can use `user.posts.left_join(:media)` to ensure that the returned posts have a `media` associated. If not using Rails 5, you can manually define the join (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins). And this will also solve your n+1 query problem.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should not make the calls to the db/model (with `limit`) in the views. Call it directly in the controller :
`@posts = user.posts.order(created_at: :desc).limit(6)`

Then, I would do some debugging to be sure you have the records you want.

Use byebug for instance and call it just after you set you `@posts` instance variable to see what it contains. Do all the posts contain a media ?

Comment: another option is to have a `else` block for the `if post.media.present?` and display something like `"no media for post #{post.id}"`

Comment: I knew this would come up. In my view I am also viewing all the users posts and i do not intend to limit those. The alternative was to create another variable to handle this but that would have me calling querying the db twice for the same resource, wouldn't it?
And yes. I had tried this too

Comment: @MrYoshiji, for my codes purposes, this works just fine as there are some html css code present. I wouldn't like to render them if no images are found

Comment: maybe a default image?